# Passing dict as parameter for COLUMN_CREATE() in mariadb

Tags: python, dynamic, mariadb

I want to add dynamic columns into mariadb table. Each time I may have to add different set of columns. 
If I know the columns, I can create like below.

```
arg1='Color'
arg2='Blue'
query="INSERT INTO items (name, attributes) VALUES ('Shirt',      COLUMN_CREATE(%s,%s))"
db.execute(query,(arg1,arg2))
conn.commit()
```

But, I am using function which takes dictionary as parameter, I need to pass that values as parameters to COLUMN_CREATE().
I tried below code in python. But its not working,, Please help me.

```
args={'color':'blue','size':'XX'}
query="INSERT INTO items (name, attributes) VALUES ('Shirt',     COLUMN_CREATE(%s))"
db.execute(query,(args))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Show us the query _after_ python has done the substitution.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mariadb-dyncol